# Bootstrap3: what is the proper way to change navbar-collapse div to fullscreen menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make the `div` of `navbar-collapse` dropping to 100% browser height when the menu clicked, [like this one.](https://codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/BLjwu) But I got confused how to implement it to [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/9jb9Lywb/1/)

I tried this:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
    min-height:100%;  //doesn't work for me
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
    min-height:500px //using px sure is resize the div but I don't think this is the proper way    
}
```

but nothing is work. Need help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS code snippet:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q65y8zoa/)

Comment: Thanks, @herrh. It sure did the trick on mobile view, but doesn't work on desktop view, even after I add the css to media breakpoint rule. Any other suggest?

Comment: ah! i see, it works both mobile and desktop view, if we change the `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh;`. But I still don't know if it's the proper way to use `vh` instead of percentage? Because the transition when the menu slide-up and down seems a bit odd.

Comment: @teacup Glad I could help. vw/vh is relative to the size of the viewport, whereas percent values are relative to the container.  Please accept the answer and click the tick below the answer rating if it solved your problem..

Comment: sure @herrh. maybe i should make another post about the odd transition of navbar.

Comment: @teacup, yes I think so.